# Pyserial: Could not configure port: (22, 'Invalid argument')

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtual-machine, pyserial, beagleboneblack

On Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox, with a Beaglebone Black connected to a USB port, running the following code returns an error:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = '/dev/sdb'
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.open()
```

Error:

```
Could not configure port: (22, 'Invalid argument')
```

I acquired the BBB's path using `blkid` in the terminal. The BBB is normally accessible using SSH in the virtual Machine.

What is causing the error, why can't Python open the port? 

**Edit** 
The output of `blkid` is:

```
/dev/sr0: UUID="2017-07-17-16-26-18-00" LABEL="VBOXADDITIONS_5.1.24_117012" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/sda1: UUID="58957263-a785-44f1-89a0-a66efd56623f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="306fada4-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="2e8ad169-1527-4336-9169-e189688038cd" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="306fada4-05"
/dev/sdb: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="boot" UUID="0CD5-4AE7" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="WATTO" UUID="BAF1-8FE6" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="1299f9fa-01"
```

Where `/dev/sdb` is the BBB's path and `/dev/sdc1` the USB stick's path.

`ls -l /dev/sd*` returns:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 jul 31 11:14 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 jul 31 11:14 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  2 jul 31 11:14 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  5 jul 31 11:14 /dev/sda5
brw-rw-rw- 1  666 disk 8, 16 jul 31 16:32 /dev/sdb
brw------- 1 root root 8, 32 jul 31 16:52 /dev/sdc
brw------- 1 root root 8, 33 jul 31 16:52 /dev/sdc1
```

`lsblk` returns:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   12G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   10G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   96M  0 disk /media/alexander/boot
sdc      8:32   1  7,5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1  7,5G  0 part /media/alexander/WATTO
sr0     11:0    1 56,8M  0 rom  /media/alexander/VBOXADDITIONS_5.1.24_1170123
```

Comment: `/dev/sdb` is not a serial port--it's usually a file storage drive of some kind.  A serial port usually looks like `/dev/ttyS0` or `/dev/ttyUSB0` or similar.

Comment: If I plug in a USB stick, it's path is: `/dev/sdc/`. Could this behaviour be due to VirtualBox?

Comment: Share your blkid output, as @jszakmeister wrote /dev/sdb is usually mapped to hard-drives

Comment: I edited my question using the output. Please view above

Comment: You are trying to "open" your disk partition as a serial port. Use instead the devices with such names as @jszakmeister has proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the wrong device name: read the link at the end in this case, VirtualBox may well misunderstand the host USB serial devices, and hence have assigned the wrong device (/dev) name.

"/dev/sdb" is probably a block device such as a hard drive.

```
$ ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jul 31 13:59 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Jul 31 13:59 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Jul 31 13:59 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 5 Jul 31 13:59 /dev/sda5
^
Note 'b' for block device
```

The serial ports will be such as "/dev/ttyUSB0"

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jul 31 14:34 /dev/ttyUSB0
^
Note 'c' for character device
```

Serial ports often have group set to 'dialout' - but this is just for information, this gets set as part of recognition that it is a serial port.

You may also wish to read this item on using host serial USB devices under VirtualBox: https://techtooltip.wordpress.com/2008/09/12/using-host-serial-port-from-guest-in-virtual-box/

Comment: I added myself to the dialout group, still the error persists. I added some output to the original question, please view above

Comment: Read that item I have posted - your membership of dialout has  no bearing on the matter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems the problem lies in VirtualBoxe's Serial Port settings. I followed the above tutorial, but I'm getting another error when trying to run the guest machine. I've posted [a new question regarding the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439160/virtualbox-failed-to-open-host-device-com1-verr-file-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

The Beaglebone seems to only show its filesystem via USB connection: /dev/sdb
If you want to connect to it via Serial connection, you need a USB to TTY converter. (for example a PL2303HX, 2$-10$).
Also you could follow this tutorial to connect the pc to your serial port.

http://www.dummies.com/computers/beaglebone/how-to-connect-the-beaglebone-black-via-serial-over-usb/